# Filter rows with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with different `speaker`s and `utterance`s, of which those occurring in overlap are in `[...]`; the `df` also contains `starttime_ms`and `endtime_ms` values:

```
df <- data.frame(
  speaker = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A"),
  utterance = c("hi [there] long time no [see] how're things", "[howdy]", 
                "[yeah]", "we're [good]", "[great]", "[really]", "yeah [fine]", "[and y]ourself?"),
  starttime_ms = c(10, 25, 444, 1133, 1400, 1567, 1800, 1974),
  endtime_ms = c(1100, 125, 555, 1566, 1566, 1700, 2000, 2111)
)
```

I need to filter those rows (i) where `utterance`consists entirely (from start to end) of an `[...]` expression and (ii) where `endtime_ms` is smaller than `endtime_ms` by the **prior speaker**.

The **expected result** is this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   grp [2]
  speaker utterance starttime_ms endtime_ms   grp
  <chr>   <chr>            <dbl>      <dbl> <int>
1 B       [howdy]             25        125     2
2 B       [yeah]             444        555     2
```

I can filter according to condition (i):

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(speaker)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("^\\[[^][]+\\]$", utterance))
```

but I don't know how to implement condition (ii); using `& lag(endtime_ms) > endtime_ms` as another condition for `filter` did not work.

Comment: *"`endtime_ms` is smaller"* doesn't seem right: 555 is not less than 125.

Comment: (It appears you are using `data.table::rleid`, it would be good to include that.)

Comment: Just to clarify, by "`endtime_ms` is smaller than `endtime_ms` by the prior speaker" you mean on the grouped data before you filter by first condition?

Comment: @LeonardoViotti Correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to stick with the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  speaker = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A"),
  utterance = c("hi [there] long time no [see] how're things", "[howdy]", 
                "[yeah]", "we're [good]", "[great]", "[really]", "yeah [fine]", "[and y]ourself?"),
  starttime_ms = c(10, 25, 444, 1133, 1400, 1567, 1800, 1974),
  endtime_ms = c(1100, 125, 555, 1566, 1566, 1700, 2000, 2111)
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    speaker2 = lag(speaker),
    endtime_ms2 = lag(endtime_ms)
  ) %>%
  mutate(endtime_ms2 = case_when(
    speaker == speaker2 ~ NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ endtime_ms2
  )) %>%
  fill(endtime_ms2) %>%
  filter(endtime_ms < endtime_ms2) %>%
  select(-contains("2"))
#>   speaker utterance starttime_ms endtime_ms
#> 1       B   [howdy]           25        125
#> 2       B    [yeah]          444        555
```

Comment: But what if there's an `utterance` that is **not** `[...]` and stilll has `endtime_ms`smaller than the `endtime_ms`of the prior speaker's `utterance`?

Comment: I think your solution is closest to what I have in mind. I'd like to accept it if you could address the issue raised in my previous comment. That is, how can the constraint be built in that only `utterance`s are selected that match the `^[...]$` pattern?

Comment: I think I've got it: `filter(grepl("^\\[[^][]+\\]$", utterance)) `

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` go at your problem..

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df) #make it a data.table
#first filter in [...] strings in utterance
ans <- df[ grepl("^\\[.*\\]$", utterance ), ]
#create a temparary column with the maximum endtime_ms of the previous group
ans[, temp := shift( ans[, max(endtime_ms), 
                         by = rleid(speaker)]$V1)[.GRP], 
    by = rleid(speaker)]
#now filtering is easy, drop the temp-column afterward
ans[ is.na(temp) | endtime_ms < temp, ][, temp := NULL][]
#    speaker utterance starttime_ms endtime_ms
# 1:       B   [howdy]           25        125
# 2:       B    [yeah]          444        555
```

Comment: edit: forgot to group by rleid(speaker)... fixed now

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question. The code below should do it.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(
  speaker = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A"),
  utterance = c("hi [there] long time no [see] how're things", "[howdy]", 
                "[yeah]", "we're [good]", "[great]", "[really]", "yeah [fine]", "[and y]ourself?"),
  starttime_ms = c(10, 25, 444, 1133, 1400, 1567, 1800, 1974),
  endtime_ms = c(1100, 125, 555, 1566, 1566, 1700, 2000, 2111)
)


# Get min endtime by speaker
min_endtime_df <- 
  df %>% group_by(speaker) %>% 
    summarise(endtime_ms_l = min(endtime_ms)) %>% 
  # Shift the speakers to merge
  mutate(speaker = lead(speaker))

# Merge with the previous group
df %>% 
  merge(min_endtime_df,
        by = 'speaker',
        all = T) %>%
  # First condition
  filter(endtime_ms_l > endtime_ms) %>% 
  # Second conditon 
  group_by(grp = rleid(speaker)) %>%
  filter(grepl("^\\[[^][]+\\]$", utterance))
```